# Attempting to allocate a contiguous memory block and access it using 3 indices, but my method segfaults

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am attempting to write a procedure that lets me allocate a contiguous block of memory of size n1*n2*n3 and access it using 3 indices, like you would with an array

```
int array[n1][n2][n3];
```

I have successfully (as far as I can tell) managed this with two indices (see my example below)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    // Dimensions
    const int n1 = 2;
    const int n2 = 2;

    int **array;

    // Pointers
    array = (int **)malloc(n1*sizeof(int *));

    // Contiguous chunk of memory of size n1xn2
    array[0] = (int *)malloc(n1*n2*sizeof(int));

    // Pointer arithmetic
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++) {
        array[i] = array[0] + i*n2;
    }

    array[0][0] = 1;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But when I try a similar construct with three indices, my procedure throws a segfault:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    // Dimensions
    const int n1 = 2;
    const int n2 = 2;
    const int n3 = 2;

    int ***array;

    // Pointers
    array = (int ***)malloc(n1*sizeof(int **));
    array[0] = (int **)malloc(n1*n2*sizeof(int *));

    // Contiguous chunk of memory of size n1xn2xn3
    array[0][0] = (int *)malloc(n1*n2*n3*sizeof(int));

    // Pointer arithmetic
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++) {
            array[i][j] = array[0][0] + i*n2*n3 + j*n2;
        }
    }

    array[0][0][0] = 1;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I understand there are other ways to manage a contiguous block of memory. I am specifically interested in why my logic is failing in the above case.

Comment: try just ` array = (int ***)malloc(n1**n2*n3*sizeof(int **));`

Comment: You will need another loop for assigning `array[i]`, before assigning `array[i][j]`.

Comment: Being C, you *can* do this using VLA addressing and a single allocation (assuming your toolchain actually supports it, you're SOL if using an MS tool set). So I'm not sure whether that's an option for you or not.

Comment: Do not cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing

```
array[i] = array[0] + i*n2;
```

Here is your code

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    // Dimensions
    const int n1 = 2;
    const int n2 = 2;
    const int n3 = 2;

    int ***array;

    // Pointers
    array = (int ***)malloc(n1*sizeof(int **));
    array[0] = (int **)malloc(n1*n2*sizeof(int *));

    // Contiguous chunk of memory of size n1xn2xn3
    array[0][0] = (int *)malloc(n1*n2*n3*sizeof(int));

    // Pointer arithmetic
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++) {
        array[i] = array[0] + i*n2;
        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++) {
            array[i][j] = array[0][0] + i*n2*n3 + j*n2;
        }
    }

    array[0][0][0] = 1;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Do not cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score -1):

Allocating memory for 3D array.
Maybe I did something wrong, but seems ok.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main () {
 int n1 = 2;
 int n2 = 3;
 int n3 = 4;
 int i, j;

 int ***array;

 array = malloc(n1 * sizeof(int**));

 for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    array[i] = malloc(n2 * sizeof(int*));

 for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
 for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    array[i][j] = malloc(n3 * sizeof(int));


 array[1][2][3] = 15000;
 printf("%d\n", array[1][2][3]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the memory would be contiguous in this example, as you are mallocing n1*n2 separate chunks of memory

Comment: @DJames your suspicions of discontinuity are well-founded. As soon as you introduce more than one `malloc` continuity goes out the window. This answer does not provide a single contiguous region (and neither does any of your posted code).

Comment: @DJames  True. But you can use indices.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Well, this `array[0] = (int *)malloc(n1*n2*sizeof(int));` allocates a *continues* region of memory which holds *all* `int`s of the "2D"-array.

Comment: @alk Of *that* array of arrays, but there are more than one (thus the loops). The backdrop of this, therefore, cannot be similar to `int arr[a][b][c];`, but you already knew that.